# A decentralized publisher-subscriber protocol

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, contract-design

I am here to share with you my project: Smart Contracts which represents a decentralized version of a publisher-subscriber protocol. I called that DPS.
On github https://github.com/dpsprotocol/DPS you can find a paper and the code
I would be really happy in having your comments and opinions on that

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange!  This is a Question & Answer site, so you need to format material as a Q & A.